# How GoToMeeting validate desktop software installed in order to host session

Tags: javascript, windows

Looking for a Technique where I can install my software on a windows PC and check using javascript that if the software is installed.

If installed launch it. If not installed download it.

The hint I got is to add custom font or mime type and then check it something like this - https://www.samclarke.com/javascript-is-font-available/

Comment: Your font method is good. Also is cross-platform.  Do you need example(s)?

Comment: Yes I am looking for someone who can guide me the proper way to do it.

Comment: You can do this by create an small windows app that will check if your actual software is installed, if not then it will download. You cannot access Installed Software list directly from web browser but you can access fonts because they are in the scope of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a protocol handler.

### How the check works,

It execute a custom schema url. For example.

executing the `magnet://` will redirect you to `torrent` application if installed. Else, redirect you to google. Here, in the place of google, you can use the protocol handler to redirect to the setup file.

From mobile, executing `whatsapp://` will Open whatsapp if installed.

Check the below snippet.

Running it will prompt to Open the `torrent` application.

```js
function utorrent_test(){
  return window.location.href="magnet://";
}
var result=utorrent_test();
console.log(result);
```

Read more about protocol handler in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers)

Also read in detail here https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#custom-handlers

Comment: But how and where do you register that custom schema for the whole system (all browsers)