# Web browser, detect if software handling certain file extension is installed

Tags: javascript, system, file-extension

I have custom documents that require a certain program to be installed in the system. And I need to distribute these doc files through the web.

I want to offer the download in different formats depending on the soft being or not being installed on the user's system.

Is there a way to know if a handler of certain file extension is installed in the system? (I suppose it would be with Javascript but go figure)

**Edit:** It seems that rather than an extension, it's better looking for a mime type. This will imply setting a mime type handler in the system (when installing the software) Still can't find a clear way to know from any browser if the mime type is installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How GoToMeeting validate desktop software installed in order to host session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944048/how-gotomeeting-validate-desktop-software-installed-in-order-to-host-session)

Comment: That would be such a security issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: There's no way to do that. Like Yury wrote, it would be a huge security issue.

Comment: Yes, somehow it would pose a security issue but wouldn't it be "the same level" as instructing to download the software and next to download the doc? (The browser would offer to "Open with ...". I was just wondering if it could be automated in a step)